# PHP SQL query in while loop JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, while-loop

I'm making a basic notification system for a practice project. I have several tables, two of which look something like the following:

```
> Table 1: "Users"
> 
userid | username  | Firstname | Lastname  
1      | Daffy     |   Daffy   | Duck
2      | Flinstone |   Fred    | Flinstone 
3      | dduck     |   Donald  | Duck
> 
> Table 2: "Notifications"
> 
 Notification_id | from_user_id | to_user_id | SeenOrUnseen | type    
     1           |   1          |     2      |       1      |  fRequest               
>    2           |   1          |     2      |       0      |  comment               
>    3           |   1          |     2      |       1      |  comment               
>    4           |   3          |     1      |       1      |  fRequest               
>    5           |   2          |     3      |       1      |  fRequest               
>    6           |   2          |     3      |       0      |  comment               
>    7           |   3          |     2      |       0      |  comment
```

I then need data from both these tables, and would normally JOIN the tables on the user_id and from_user_id before sending of an sql query. However, a join seems to return multiple values because in the second table there are multiple instances of from_user_id.  Instead, i'm querying the database, returning the data in a while loop, and within that while loop sending out another query to the database for a different tables' information:

```
include('../../db_login.php');
$con = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password", "$db_name");
$tbl_name = "Profile";
$tplname = "profile_template.php";
$tplname2 = "public_profile_template.php";
$myid = $_SESSION['identification'];
//CHECK CONNECTION
if(mysqli_connect_errno($con))  {
echo "failed to connect" . mysql_connect_error();
}else {
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Notifications WHERE to_user_id='$myid'");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count == 0){

    $style = "display:none;";
} else {

echo "<ul class='notifications'>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $from_user_id = $row['from_user_id'];
    $to_user_id = $row['to_user_id'];
    $seen = $row['seen'];
    $nature = $row['nature'];
        $result2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$from_user_id'");
        $count2 = mysqli_num_rows($result2);
        if($count2 != 0){
        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
        $fromFirstname = $row2['Firstname'];
        $fromLastname = $row2['Lastname'];

        }
    if($nature == 'fRequest'){
    echo "<li> You have received a friend request from" . $fromFirstname . " " . $fromLastname . "</li>";
    }
    }

    }   
    echo "</ul>";
}


mysqli_close($con);
}
                echo "<div id='NoNotification'></div>";
                echo "<div id='Notification' style='" . $style . "'></div>";
                ?>
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Yes. Rewrite as a join. You say it didn't work, but that just means you didn't write the join correctly. Nested queries like this, where the inner query depends on value(s) from the outer one, are HORRIBLY inefficient.

Comment: Yes. There is a better of doing this. If you only want DISTINCT results, select only DISTINCT results.

Comment: Cool, that's what I thought Marc B! Having another go joining, but the answer below is pretty much what I've done before. What is the best Join in this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT n.*, u.*
FROM Notifications n 
JOIN users u ON n.from_user_id=u.id
WHERE n.to_user_id=$myid
ORDER BY n.id, u.id
```

You will get all the data you need. The notification data and the user data. It is better to define which fields you want to retrieve in stead of `*` so you got a better view of what your using and your not sending data which you don't use.

Als you are using an integer (id) as a string, you can just put the `$myid` there. Also beaware this is not a safe query for MySQL injection. [For more info](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).